# Managing Occupancy in CUDA

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, gpu, nvidia

Good Morning.

I am starting learning cuda programming and I am going over performance. I read in CUDA website that in other to have good performance we should take four things in consideration:

http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/achievedoccupancy.htm

-warps per SM(system multiprocessor)
 -blocks per SM
 -Register per SM
 -Shared memory per SM

So I am going over the to first things and, depending on the GPU I defined the dimensions of the kernel depending on the maximum warps per SM and blocks per SM. My task is performing one thousand million of sums to measure which method goes better.

What I do is a for loop in which I launch at each iteration a kernel maximizing the occupancy. For example for an NVidia 1080 GPU I read:

`int max_blocks = 32; //maximum number of active blocks per SM`
  `int max_threads_per_Block = 64; //maximum number of active threads per SM`
  `int max_threads = 2048;`

This gives in total 2048 threads per SM and guarantees maximum occupancy. This GPU can have 64 active warps each one with 32 threads. In this GPU one active block have 2 warps and that means each block can have 64 active threads at once. With this I launch the kernel as follows:

`dim3 threadsPerBlock(max_threads_per_Block);`
  `dim3 numBlocks(max_blocks);`
`VecAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C,max_threads);`

What I surprisingly notice is that if I launch this kernel directly like:

`int N = total_ops; //in this case one thousand millions`
  `dim3 threadsPerBlock(256);`
   `dim3 numBlocks(2*N / threadsPerBlock.x);`
`VecAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C,);`

The performance is better (time consumed). I launch the same experiment 5 times in the same execution to avoid outliers. My question is: is there any way to manage the occupancy to have better results than what the compiler and run time API does?. I understand that the optimization I try to do is already manage by the GPU in some way. I understand that if there is a document explaining how we should launch software (link above) in order to achieve good performance it should be a way to control this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In your first example,

```
int max_blocks = 32;            //maximum number of active blocks per SM
int max_threads_per_Block = 64; //maximum number of active threads per SM
int max_threads = 2048;

dim3 threadsPerBlock(max_threads_per_Block);
dim3 numBlocks(max_blocks);
VecAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C,max_threads);
```

you are launching as many blocks and threads per block as needed to fully load *one* SM. However your GTX 1080 has *20* SMs, so your occupancy is only 1/20 = 5%.

In the second example,

```
int N = total_ops;              //in this case one thousand millions
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256);
dim3 numBlocks(2*N / threadsPerBlock.x);
VecAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C,);
```

you are launching a large number of blocks, which allows the GPU to execute as many in parallel as needed to get to 100% occupancy (resources permitting, which should not be an issue in case of a simple vector add). Hence the better performance.

While you could just multiply the number of blocks by 20 in your first example to get to the same performance as the second, the pattern from the second example is preferred as it does not refer to the specific configuration of the GPU used. So the code will fully load any of a large range of GPUs.

On a side note, vector addition as a memory bound algorithm is not particularly well suited to demonstrating the effect of occupancy. However you are still seeing a difference as a certain minimum number of memory transactions in flight is needed to fully load the memory subsystem (determined by memory bandwidth times the latency of a memory access), and the 5% occupancy example falls short of this minimum.

Comment: so really the best thin to do is:

Comment: Sorry, the best thing to do should be:
int N = total_ops;              //in this case one thousand millions
dim3 threadsPerBlock(256);
dim3 numBlocks(2*N / threadsPerBlock.x);
VecAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C,);

Comment: Sorry again. The really best thing to do should not be:

int N = total_ops;              //in this case one thousand millions
int max_threads_per_Block = 64; //maximum number of active threads per SM

dim3 threadsPerBlock(max_threads_per_Block);
dim3 numBlocks(2*N / threadsPerBlock.x);
VecAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C,);

Would this  ensure each block has all its threads active and thus performance is increased?